# How to process fluky but necessary file in git?

Tags: git

For example, `banne.gif`,`config_mysql.php`.
`banner.gif` is necessary when coding because we need to check css layout,and designer always change it.
`config_mysql.php` is necessary when coding because we need this file to run mysql,and we cannot use `production version`.

I am not sure whether `git add` those files or put those files in `.gitignore`.
What's the best way to process those kinds of files in git?

Comment: Why can't banner.gif be inside the repository, it seems like something that is part of the appliacation and should thus be sourcce controlled together with the code?

Comment: too many pics,too big git warehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keeping environment specific configuration values outside of the source controlled code repository** is generally a good idea since code should be able to run anywhere, only configuration should change.

## Solution 1: Sample files

Instead of keeping `config_mysql.php` inside the reposiotry keep a file called `config_mysql.php.sample` and add `config_mysql.php` to `.gitignore`

People cloning or branching out from master locally can then specify their property values `config_mysql.php`, which is added to `.gitignore` and thus not impacting the git tree. A developer only edits the `config_mysql.php.sample` file if config is added/removed (which is information that needs to be added to the source code repository)

## Solution 2: Keep configuration values in environment variables

Instead of specifying the actual values for the keys in `config_mysql.php.sample` pull them from environment variables.

```
$db_host = $_SERVER["MYAPP_DB_HOST"];
$db_user = $_SERVER["MYAPP_DB_USER"];
// and so on
```

This way there is only one configuration file, which is under source control together with the code, and developers set their local values by setting environment variables. Shared enviornments like prodution and staging need to either be prepared with those environment variables or the deployment tool can take care of injecting them.

## Summary

I tend to like solution 2 better, since there is no need for sample files and it is easy to override configuration). It can even be extended by providing default values if the environment variable is not set. This is not suitable for all types of configuration values and should be used with care to avoid accidental connections to for example a production database

Answer (score 0):

There's not really one answer that's always right.  It can depend on any number of things.  Some very general advice follows, and you can find more information from existing questions/answers.

*Image Files*

If they're small and/or not frequently changing, you can consider just `add`ing them and not worry too much about it.  While git isn't *as* good at handling binary files, the main problem they cause is bloating the repository; and at moderate sizes it's not a big problem.

For the purpose you describe, you might reduce the size (and possibly the frequency of change) by using properly-dimensioned placeholders.

If image files are going to be a problem, you could use a tool like `git lfs`, which keeps the repo size under control by providing a secondary repo for files like large binaries.

*Environment-specific Files*

My general advice is to `.gitignore` these and use your build project to bring in (and/or construct) the correct version for the build's target environment.  For example, you could check in a template file from which each environment's version of the file could be constructed, then have your build process fill in the template based on a variable that specifies the environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can have two versions of `banner.gif` and `config_mysql.php`.

For example, you can check in to Git these files: 
`config_mysql.php` and `config_mysql_dev.php`

On production, use `config_mysql.php` file.

And on your local machine, you can rename the file `config_mysql_dev.php` to `config_mysql.php` 
to use it.

Similar things can be thought for banner.gif...

Comment: Renaming `config_mysql_dev.php` to `config_mysql.php` is not very flexible as it assumes all developers use the same local setup and it will generate conflicts in pulls. It can also be dangerous as the production credentials are distributed to all developers and they are used by default ...

Comment: Developing an application should not require credentials for the production database. If the developers also operates the application fine, they need the credentials for that purpose, but if not there should be no reason. My point is a) that your suggestion leaves no choice but to share the db credentials with anybody with access to the repository, and b) that they are used by default, if you just clone the repo and do nothing else you will connet to the production database. Those reasons are why I think your suggestion is a bad practice that should be discouraged.